# Dúvida - inserir máscara html

Tags: html5, front-end

Olá,

estou precisando colocar uma máscara da seguinte forma:

Tenho um campo:

`<input type="text" required maxlength="4" name="minimumGrade"  id="minimumGrade" ng-model="capacity.minimumGrade">`

E preciso que nesse campo ele receba somente três dígitos (números) e que ao digitar ele fique com uma máscara dessa forma:

`#.##`

Deverá ficar em forma de "nota", exemplo: 9.00, 7.50 e assim vai...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="number" pattern="(\d{3})([\.])(\d{2})">
```

deve resolver teu problema, porem não é bem uma mascara será necessário colocar os pontos e virgulas.

mascara apenas com js

[jQuery-Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: Não deu certo como o pattern, passa a qtd de caracteres que desejo...

Comment: http://html5pattern.com/Dates para mais sobre o pattern

Exemplo utilizando o jquery-Mask
(precisa do jquery)

https://jsfiddle.net/1zt9abp2/

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Como o @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba citou, com o `attribute pattern` o usuário ainda deverá colocar o `.` ou a `,`.

Para realmente colocar uma máscara, utilize a biblioteca **JQuery Mask Plugin** do Igor Escobar.
Com ela, você pode utilizar a anotações para facilitar seu código e que funciona muito bem.

Seu código ficará assim:

```
<input type="text" required maxlength="4" name="minimumGrade"  id="minimumGrade" ng-model="capacity.minimumGrade" data-mask="9.99">
```

E o resultado desse `input` será como esperado:
7.89, 9.45, 2.47.

Comment: Olá, fiz conforme passou acima importei as bibliotecas, mas não funciona... Tem como me mandar um exemplo?